# Try to handle font files with filepond

Tags: fonts, upload, mime-types, filepond

i'll use vue-filepond to upload fonts and other files to my vue project. Unfortunately, the type (MIME-Type) ist not correctly detected. The value of type is an empty string.

I use the filepond-plugin-file-validate-type plugin but i think it don't work correctly with font types. I've try to use the soluton below, but i don't know how i can use this with vue-filepond: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/file-validate-type/#custom-type-detection.

Can you help me please or did you have an idea?

I've try to upload ttf and otf files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the FilePond template on the [vue-filepond](https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond/) repository.

I haven't tested this but it should give you an idea of how to link up the custom file validation function (in this case `'myValidation'`).

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <file-pond
      name="test"
      ref="pond"
      label-idle="Drop files here..."
      v-bind:allow-multiple="true"
      accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
      server="/api"
      v-bind:fileValidateTypeDetectType="myValidation"
      v-bind:files="myFiles"
      v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Import Vue FilePond
import vueFilePond from "vue-filepond";

// Import FilePond styles
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";

// Import FilePond plugins
// Please note that you need to install these plugins separately

// Import image preview plugin styles
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css";

// Import image preview and file type validation plugins
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";

// Create component
const FilePond = vueFilePond(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);

export default {
  name: "app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      myValidation: (source, type) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if (source.name.endsWith('woff')) return 'font/woff';

            resolve(type);
        }),
      myFiles: ["cat.jpeg"]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleFilePondInit: function () {
      console.log("FilePond has initialized");

      // FilePond instance methods are available on `this.$refs.pond`
    },
  },
  components: {
    FilePond,
  },
};
</script>
```