# Vue FilePond thinks all font files are invalid

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, filepond

I have just upgraded a VueJS website from version 2 to 3, I use Vue File Pond to allow users to upload files.

The File Pond Uploader is working fine for all file types I allow except font files.  If I try and upload a font file I get
an error message saying 'Invalid File Type' with a list of the name of valid font file types passed in via the accepted-file-types property.

The error is happening at the pre upload stage as I do not see a request server side or anything on the Chrome Dev Tools' Network tab.

All the details are below, hopefully this can be resolved in what is a very good File Uploader Component.

**Details:**

Seems like it could be the same issue as this:

[Try to handle font files with filepond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69077019/try-to-handle-font-files-with-filepond)

Which was raised as a result of:

https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond/issues/214

Tried using a variety of fonts and types including ones from https://fonts.google.com/

**Vue Compoent:**

```
<file-pond
 ref="filepond"
 credits="false"
 name="file"
 style-button-remove-item-position="right"
 :allow-multiple="true"
 :allow-file-type-validation="true"
 :accepted-file-types="fontFileTypes"
 :drop-on-element="dropOnElement"
 :element="root"
 :max-files="5"
 :server="server"
/>
```

adding this validates and the files pass but the error still happens:

:file-validate-type-detect-type="customValidator"

custom validator is based on https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/file-validate-type/#custom-type-detection

changing allow-file-type-validation to false allows the files through as expected

accepted-file-types is:

`function fontFileTypes() { return ['font/ttf', 'font/woff', 'font/woff2']; }`

I also tried checking the mime types via C# code using https://github.com/zone117x/MimeMapping

My font files gave the same mime types as above, I also tried some variants as well like the below but made no difference to FilePond:

`.woff - application/font-woff .ttf - application/x-font-truetype`

**Vue App:**

VueJS 3 - Composition API, Vite, Javascript:

`"vue": "^3.3.8", "filepond": "^4.28.0", "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.6", "vue-filepond": "7.0.4",`

**Browsers:**

Edge and Chrome

I tried different font files (TTF, WOFF, WOFF2, OTF etc) and even allowing any files, the 'invalid file type' message still appeared and stopped the upload